# remove gazebo2 and install gazebo7 for ros indigo

Tags: gazebo-2.2, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have installed Indigo: host gazebo version 2.x package before.

Now I want to change gazebo2 to gazebo7, **do I need to remove the gazebo2 and all the gazebo2 package related first**, and then follow the official install tutorial?

If so, how to remove them cleanly, correctly and safely?

By the way, I also wonder if gazebo7 and ros-gazebo7 package installed, will any code which run on ros-gazebo2 run well on ros-gazebo7 as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16092/remove-gazebo2-and-install-gazebo7-for-ros-indigo/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yew, you have to remove gazebo2 first. Use this command: `$ sudo apt-get remove gazebo2*`.
And then you follow the official tutorial. The easiest way is using the official [script](https://github.com/nubot-nudt/simatch/blob/master/gazebo7_install.sh), which I put in my own [repository](https://github.com/nubot-nudt/simatch) and you are free to download.

And then if you want to integrate ROS and Gazebo well, then you are recommended to install ros-gazebo package using the following command: `$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo7-ros-pkgs`. Since there are some API modifications, chances are that you have to modify some functions in order to be compatible with Gazebo 7 if it was used in Gazebo 2 initially.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2017-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-22**:
Thanks, you are really helpful!

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-30**:
I encounter anther problem related to gazebo-ros, could u please give me a hint? Thanks.
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16314/catkin-error-gazebo-ros-control-missing-on-indigo-plus-gazebo7/

**Comment by [Cyril_J](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5933/cyril_j/) on 2018-07-13**:
When I try to remove gazebo*, apt-get ask me to remove ros-kinetic-desktop-full, which I want to keep. How do you change the flag that enforces that removal ?